# How to store and compare dates in a SQL database

Tags: c#, mysql, database, datetime, date-format

I am working on a Windows Forms C# project. I have a sale table in a MySQL database and this table has a column of `Date` named `varchar`. When I pass  a current date as a string from `sale.cs` C# it gets stored correctly.

```cs
string a = datetime.now.date.toshortdatestring();
```

But when I try to apply MySQL between query on sale it doesn't work properly as only the day is compared with day..month and year is not compared.

This is my query:

```sql
select * from sale where date between '"+textbox1.text+"' and '"+textbox2+"'
```

I want to save the current date at the time of sale and I want to get a report of from one date to other date. What is the column type in xamp `Date` , `varchar` or `datetime` and how can I save the current time as `datetime` or `string`? How do I get the report from one date to other also comparing the month and year?

Comment: ` a column of Date named as varchar` Dates are not strings and dates *only* have a format when stored as strings.  Dont do that - store date data as Date.

Comment: Use parameterized SQL queries, as you're supposed to.

Comment: Also: `ToShortDateString()` is non-deterministic. The format is system-dependent, where you can see different formats from one machine to the next. Someone could configure it to not even include real data at all, or you could end up with a mix of formats that result in ambiguity. Mix a UK citizen and US citizen talking to the same DB, and suddenly 2/3/2019 could represent both Feb 3 or Mar 2. You _really_ should be storing this data in a DateTime column. _If you ever find yourself converting an .Net DateTime variable to a string for use in SQL, you're doing something **very** wrong._

Answer (score 0):

There are several things here we need to address.

First up is an easy one. `BETWEEN` is probably not the best option to use for ranged reports, since it is inclusive of values at both edges of the range. You end update double counting anything that happens at exactly midnight. Better to structure the query like this:

```
select * from sale where date >= '"+textbox1.text+"' and date < '"+textbox2+"'
```

This gives us an exclusive upper bound on the date range. Sometimes, users expect the inclusive upper bound on a date range query, but even in these cases that will coincide with also expect the upper bound to include the *full day*. So a user will enter something like `7/25/2019` and want to get all of today's data. But on the datebase side, there is an implied time of midnight at the beginning of the day, and you still miss out. So what you do is *add a day* to the input, and *still use the exclusive upper bound*.

Moving on. You *REALLY* should be storing this data in a `DateTime` column. It's not okay at all put Date data into varchar columns! Additionally, *if you ever find yourself converting an .Net DateTime variable to a string for use in SQL, you're doing something **very** wrong.*

The `ToShortDateString()` method here is especially bad, because it's non-deterministic. The format is system-dependent, where you can see different formats from one machine to the next. Someone could configure it to not even include real data at all. More likely you eventually end up with a mix of formats that result in ambiguity. Mix a UK citizen and US citizen talking to the same DB, and suddenly `2/3/2019` could represent both `Feb 3` or `Mar 2`, depending on who entered the data. That's just one example of many.

Even worse is the string concatenation in the query. A user could put *anything* there. For example: `';DROP TABLE sale; --`. Think carefully about what would happen with that value in your textbox. You might never see anything this bad, but there are plenty of ways real users will break that field purely by accident.

It may be tempting now to try to sanitize these textbox inputs, but that is not answer. Sanitizing inputs only takes you so far, and puts you into a game of cat and mouse or whac-a-mole with your users/attackers. The better option is to **quarantine** your inputs. You do this using parameterized queries.

Correctly parameterized code for the SELECT might look like this:

```
string sql = "select * from sale where date >= @startdate and date < @enddate;";
using (var cn = new MySqlConnection("connection string here"))
using (var cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, cn))
{
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@startdate", MySqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Parse(TextBox1.Text); 
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@enddate", MySqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Parse(TextBox2.Text);

    cn.Open();
    // Fill() a dataset or cmd.ExecuteReader() here
}
```